# Can't import PIXI js as a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pixi.js

I am trying to set a simple testing environment for PIXI js but the console debuger chokes at the import from PIXI

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "pixi.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Pixi.js has been installed with `npm install pixi.js` I am not experienced with webpack but it seems to be the problem.

`index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Animator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.js` :

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js"

...
```

`webpack.config.js` :

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: 'src/index.html', to: './' },
            { from: 'src/style.css', to: './' },
        ]),
    ],
};
```

Any idea what causes this to happen ?

Comment: Here you have <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>. And the "filename: 'app.js'". Can this be the culprit? If you just compile your app with webpack, does the resulting app.js look good?

Comment: my understanding of webpack is limited. `filename: app.js` seems to be the outpout and not a relative path. I have no app.js file created. Only index.js and index.html

Comment: May I suggest you create absolutely minimal project to reproduce your issue? Webpack is a moduler bundler. You have configured it to take "./src/app.js", look at all its dependencies and generate the single "./dist/app.js" with all the code for your game. So remove all the plugins from webpack config, forget about even opening the web browser for the moment. Just make sure running `webpack` in the console takes your input JS files and creates output JS files that you want. Let me try to answer the question in it current form though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this error occurs in the browser. Correct?

If this is the case, the most likely culprit is that you are loading your index.js via index.html in browser directly. Browser naturally cannot locate pixi.js and fails. Yes, you might be loading index.html via webpack development server, but it just does not do anything useful at all for you.

What is the reason for using webpack in the first place? My guess is: you want to bundle your entire app/game code into the single big JS file (app.js or game.js "bundle").

If this is your intent, I suggest you do it step by step, making sure you test and understand each step in full details:

- Start with an empty webpack.config.js
- Add `entry` and point it to the main JS module of your game.
- Add some "imports" to the main JS file (both PIXI and your own modules like `mainmenu.js` or `gameplay.js`).
- Add `output` and specify, where you want to put the resulting "big bundle" of your game
- Run `webpack` in the command line, make sure it completes successfully, double check your output JS looks good (don't even try to open it in the web browser just yet).

When this works, create index.html and include the resulting "big bundle" of your game into it (just manually copying files as needed into the temporary folder). If all works fine, automate this step with webpack `CopyPlugin` or with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Finally, make sure this all works great with production minified build of the game, and with webpack development web server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pixi.js without using Webpack.
A local server must be used, as serve : https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

You could use your html page and insert the link of your pixi.js script using the mjs format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Animator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="module" src="./myfile.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the myfile.mjs using the pixi.mjs version

```
import * as PIXI from "./pixi.mjs"
```